# Command remote machine from blazor PWA

Tags: api, blazor, signalr, webassembly

I have a blazor wasm PWA with asp net 6 web Api as backend hosted in IIS (win server 2012r2). Now I need from blazor PWA to command some phisycal machine at different customer locations. From the App user need to show the current state of a single machine and modify machine parameters. So the App do the request for current machine settings, the machine responds with data, and the app can modify and save the settings to the machine. The PWA must be able to communicate with one machine at a time choice from a list. So the PWA communicate with Api and Api need to have a bidirectional communication with the client machine. Is this the correct way? Which technology is suitable for this purpose? Signal R (between the server and the machine)? Than you